# Typescript tsd definition for cordova-plugin-geolocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript, tsd

I'm migrating my angular javascript code to typescript.

Therefor I would like to access the definition of $cordovaGeolocation service, from the cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin, while I'm editing my code.

I didn't find any matching services in the cordova.tsd (or I missed it).

Anyone knows if there is a service and tsd definition for it and where do I'll find it?

Thx in advance

Comment: You can always [write your own `.d.ts` file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html). It doesn't have to include all of the API, start with what you use and work your way until you get something that let's you work without `any`, compiles with no errors and educates your IDE (for autocomplete n' all).

Comment: Yep I know, but I thought why writing something incomplete by my own when a good tsd definition may already exists

Comment: How about [this one I found](https://github.com/slavomirvojacek/adbrain-typescript-definitions/blob/master/ng-cordova/geolocation.d.ts)

Comment: Great game, absolutely, that solve my inquiry. Thx!